# Fastest way in numpy to check if vectors are aligned or have opposite direction (truncated SVD post processing)

Tags: python, numpy, vector, svd, eigenvalue

I have a bunch of vectors that are stored in the columns of a matrix U.
I have also a matrix V containing column vectors. Each vector in V can either be

- almost identical to its counterpart in U, with numerical approximations
- or have an opposite sign, with numerical approximations.

The goal is to find an array containing either 1 if the vectors have the same direction, or -1 if they have opposite directions.

Two additional things:

- I am only interested in the first signs, not all (100 out of 10000 in the example below).
- V is given in its transposed form (Vt)

I have found three ways so far to solve this problem:

```
from timeit import timeit
import numpy as np

# create fake SVD output
n_components = 100
n_samples = 10000
U = np.random.random((n_samples, n_samples - 1))
true_signs = np.sign(np.random.random(n_samples - 1) - 0.5)
Vt = np.multiply(U, true_signs[None, :]).T
# simulate some numerical imprecision
Vt += np.random.random((n_samples - 1, n_samples)) * 0.001

# 3 competing methods
def compute_signs_dot():
    VtU = np.dot(Vt[:n_components, :], U[:, :n_components])
    signs = np.sign(np.diag(VtU))
    np.testing.assert_equal(signs, true_signs[:n_components])

def compute_signs_mul():
    diag_VtU = np.multiply(Vt[:n_components, :].T,
                          U[:, :n_components]).sum(axis=0)
    signs = np.sign(diag_VtU)
    np.testing.assert_equal(signs, true_signs[:n_components])

def compute_signs_sign():
    signs = np.multiply(np.sign(Vt[:n_components, :].T),
                        np.sign(U[:, :n_components])).sum(axis=0)
    signs = np.sign(signs)
    np.testing.assert_equal(signs, true_signs[:n_components])

# compare execution times
print("compute_signs_dot: %.3fs" % timeit(compute_signs_dot, number=100))
print("compute_signs_mul: %.3fs" % timeit(compute_signs_mul, number=100))
print("compute_signs_sign: %.3fs" % timeit(compute_signs_sign, number=100))
```

yields

```
compute_signs_dot: 2.001s
compute_signs_mul: 0.786s
compute_signs_sign: 1.693s
```

So it seems that the fastest method so far is to compute the scalar product between pairs of vectors at each column index by multiplying term by term and sum (`compute_signs_mul`).

Any other method would be appreciated, faster or with similar speed.

Note: as some readers will have noted, this is postprocessing on output from a truncated SVD in order to transform the singular values into eigenvalues by finding their signs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
diag_VtU = np.einsum('ji,ij->j',Vt[:n_components, :], U[:, :n_components])
```

Alternatively, with `np.matmul/@-operator` to get `diag_VtU` -

```
(Vt[:n_components, :][:,None,:] @ (U[:, :n_components].T)[:,:,None])[:,0,0]
```

Comment: Impressive ! compute_signs_dot: 2.513s
compute_signs_mul: 0.866s
compute_signs_sign: 1.755s
compute_signs_einsum: 0.373s
compute_signs_matmul: 0.355s

Comment: note: increasing the number of runs, both seem to have equivalent execution times.